# Repeat and sum value within Pandas df column with certain window size

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe of > 50000 rows and 34 columns. I need to assign a window of values in the column when a condition is met.

The condition is to repeat the preceding value with a sort of rolling window.

If value is True append 1 for the next values with window size n (e.g. 3). If within the window there are values overlapped sum them

I think it could be something like:

```
df.rolling(window=3)
```

e.g

```
NaN
NaN
1
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
1
NaN
1
NaN
```

would become:

```
NaN
NaN
1
1
1
NaN
NaN
1
1
2
1
```

Comment: Can you provide a better example? This one looks like `fillna` would suffice.

Comment: I think `fillna` will not work as it has to fill for a certain windopw of values. That is, in this example for the next 5 rows in that particular column. I will edit it to make it more clear, thanks.

Comment: So `fillna(method='ffill', limit=3)`?

Comment: The previous value is not always a NaN and sometimes as in the elif it has to be added

Comment: To be honest a good example covering all cases would go a long way. Reading your code is too difficult.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to improve the example. I hope now it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is:

```
df.fillna(0).rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).sum()
```